# DBpedia SPARQL to eliminate unwanted data

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

```
PREFIX  category:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
SELECT DISTINCT ?attractions 
                ?location
WHERE 
  {  ?attractions  dcterms:subject  ?places
  .       ?places  skos:broader     ?border
  .  ?attractions  dbpprop:location|dbpedia-owl:locatedInArea|dbpprop:locale ?location
  .    FILTER( ?border = category:Visitor_attractions_in_Delhi )
  }
```

I have above query giving result of attraction location of Delhi. I need to make it generic for all places, and secondly I want to filter out unwanted data. I want only attraction places, e.g., I didn't want `List of Monuments` and `SelectCityWalk` like data in my output.

Comment: And what have you tried?  What didn't work about it?  Can you give some specific examples of what you mean by "make it generic for all places" and what sort of things you want to be able to filter out?

Comment: Stack Overflow is focused on programming questions.  This doesn't seem to be a programming question.  DBpedia questions are often better raised on the [DBpedia discussion mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion).  SPARQL, Linked Data, and related questions are often better raised on [answers.semanticweb.com](http://answers.semanticweb.com/).